# HtmlUnit. How can I get site content updated by ajax and websockets?

Tags: ajax, htmlunit

I need to fetch comments from this site https://russian.rt.com/, for example, for this news: https://russian.rt.com/sport/article/486467-rossiya-hokkei-zoloto-olimpiady
So I try this:

```
String url = "https://russian.rt.com/sport/article/486467-rossiya-hokkei-zoloto-olimpiady";
try (WebClient client = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_52)) {
    client.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    client.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
    client.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
    client.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());
    HtmlPage rtPage = client.getPage(agencyURL);
    HtmlElement comBlock = rtPage.getFirstByXPath("//ul[@class='sppre_messages-list']");
} ...
```

But `HtmlElement comBlock` is always null.
I've tried waiting for javascript to complete by

```
 client.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(10*1000);
```

- scrolling page:

```
client.getCurrentWindow().setInnerHeight(60000);
```

or

```
rtPage.executeJavaScript("window.scrollBy(0,600)");
```

- getting elements at the bottom of the page and clicking them.
But neither of that helped and `HtmlElement comBlock` after all these operations is always null.
Maybe comments module uses some kind of websockets and this is not even possible?
Can anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

Have done some short tests with this site. At first i have seen a NPE when calling the site. This is fixed now in HtmlUnit. Usually i will inform via Twitter (www.twitter.com/HtmlUnit) if a new snapshot build is available. After that fix i faced many more javascript problems. Looks like the page does a lot of javascript including some uggly things. If you like to get this fixed it will be a great help if you can isolate simple cases that show the problems to give us a chance to fix HtmlUnit (there is more info about this on the HtmlUnit home page).

Sorry for not having a direct solution but as for many open source projects we need help from the community to do all the work.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Actually. my knowledge level of javascript and java doesn't let me help with improving htmlunit right now. And I have to use as it is. But I will keep it in mind and try to conribute as I'll get enough skills.